# Multiple IEnumerble<Entity> passed into DBContext.RemoveRange?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I recently noticed that when using DBContext.RemoveRange that I could pass in multiple comma separated IEnumarable objects into the method without a deisgn time or compilation error.

I couldn't get the intended result of removing all those IEnumerable objects in one line of code - was I using this method as intended ? I'm not sure of the term for where you can keep adding parameters into a method with seemingly no limit.

What is the intended use of RemoveRange with multiple arguments? There is no reference to using it that way on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.removerange?view=efcore-7.0

I tried passing in 4 IEnumerable objects and expected them to all be removed when calling

```
await DBContext.SaveChangesAsyc()
```

So:
`

```
var classA = await context.ClassA.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == Id);
                if (classA != null)
                {
                    var classBs = context.ClassB.Where(b => b.ClassAId == Id).Include(b => b.ClassC);
                    var ClassDs = context.ClassD.Where(d => d.ClassAId == Id);
                    foreach (var classB in classBs)
                        context.Remove(classB.ClassC);

                    context.RemoveRange(classBd, classDs, classA);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
```

Produced the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'IncludableQueryable<ClassB, ClassC>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.'

Comment: You're calling this signature: `public virtual void RemoveRange (params object[] entities)` - did you read the documentation for that? Each argument is expected to be one entity.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see - so creating the array by passing in comma separated entities - NOT passing in collections of entities. The docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.removerange?view=efcore-7.0 seem to imply you can only pass in the array OR IEnumerable. Maybe you can pass in as many entities as you like and it treats them as an array (and I have a chunk of knowledge missing as suspected).

Comment: you seem to not understand the `params` keyword. take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params